# Strange encoding for JSON output

Tags: support, api

I'm trying to create [an R API](http://www.r-project.org/).  Here's some basic code for processing JSON:

```
library(rjson)
fromJSON(readLines("http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/stats/", warn=F))
```

As I look into this, the output of readLines looks very strange:

```
[1] "\037‹\b"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[2] "\030\002úØÛy°óé½\036„iµXäË–[<üt—Zu[\\VmÎHî=ÜÛÝ¹×ýz’Í.äûû÷>ý´\a\177Ýh÷\017îÝÛÙwßÚáÿþ«¼þý\027ÅrÝæÔlgüÀëA±\017›ìŽï{M¤û.\020\037�Ë\"¿’\006³ì\032„Úß9¸ÿ`¼ç÷³*~ÿKêˆð¡\006v¦ð²ýô£�ñÃ�ì+ôU�_\026æ»½�]êt¼·?ÞûÈ4ù%\016~S0^>àe¶ÀG\037½n³éÛôKêç¼¬®‚\016Êê¢úý×u‰fó¶]=º{·aÎšŽ—y{·©î\026‹‹»h5^-/‚W1 |9[UÅ²õ^§�Ç"
[3] ":¬´¿1M\177ð\"0íö¹ñ…YÞLëbÕ*!~â\027\036§çU�®êê¢ÎˆµhòýæÅ´Zn\036S¶Z•ùv[­§óm´î�"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[4] "Í™tËª^d¥£·üÂ?¾ÿ\033'¿$ù\177"
```

Should I be using some particular kind of encoding?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**All** api results are gzipped.

So what you are looking at is a gzipped binary blob.

Simply decompress using a gzip implementation in R.

Comment: This is exactly right. What you have there is gzip'ed data.