# Possible Gzip or data format problems when trying to read JSON.

Tags: support, json, php, gzip

This is a very basic question. I just want to display a test batch of JSON with PHP, but I think I don't have the correct formatting, since the data received looks garbled when outputed, and it causes a data error if I try to decode it.

I know [the JSON data is gzipped](https://stackapps.com/questions/907/strange-encoding-for-json-output), but even with decompressing, I get an error. Here is the code I've tried:

```
<?php
  // create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?pagesize=5");

  // set options        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  // grab URL
$json = curl_exec($ch);

  // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

  // Decode JSON
var_dump(json_decode( gzuncompress($json) ));      
?>
```

The output is:

`Warning: gzuncompress() [function.gzuncompress]:

data error [on this line ==> "var_dump(json_decode( gzuncompress($json) ));"]

NULL`

(stuff in the square brackets is my translation of its, "error on line ...")

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant section of code from [stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php).

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');  // Needed by API
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

[gzuncompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) is for [ZLIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) not GZIP.  The two algorithms are related, but not identical.  gzuncompress isn't strictly guaranteed to decompress all ZLIB streams actually, its just guaranteed to decode the results of [gzcompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php).  Which is honestly really weird.

The appropriate function is [gzdecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php).
If that's not available, [http_inflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-inflate.php) should also work.

Comment: Yes, that is quite weird and somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure why gzuncompress didn't work. My version of PHP doesn't have gzdecode. But I did just find the following*:

[You can instruct curl to decompress the returned string for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002612/uncompres-a-gzip-file-from-curl-on-php/3277224#3277224) (since curl 7.10) by adding the line:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
```

[The curl_setopt PHP manual reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)